# WooCommerce search customer orders from product name or SKU

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, shortcode, orders

I'm trying to create a function inside WordPress to deploy in WooCommerce, so customers can look up for articles they've purchased by SKU or name.
The issue: is not working properly since no matter which SKU look for but same results are displayed. In addition to that, the amount of articles purchases it's always 1 as result.

```
function search_orders_by_sku_or_product_name_form() {
    ob_start();
    ?>
    <form method="post" action="">
        <input type="text" name="order_search" placeholder="enter SKU o name">
        <input type="submit" value="Search">
    </form>
    <?php
    return ob_get_clean();
}
add_shortcode('order_search_form', 'search_orders_by_sku_or_product_name_form');

function search_orders_by_sku_or_product_name_result() {
    if (isset($_POST['order_search']) && !empty($_POST['order_search'])) {
        $search_term = sanitize_text_field($_POST['order_search']);
        $user_id = get_current_user_id();

        $orders = wc_get_orders(array(
            'customer' => $user_id,
            'limit' => -1,
        ));

        $found_orders = array();

        foreach ($orders as $order) {
            $order_items = $order->get_items();

            foreach ($order_items as $item) {
                $product = $item->get_product();
                if (!$product) {
                    continue;
                }

                $sku = $product->get_sku();
                $name = $product->get_name();

                if ($sku && $name && (strpos($sku, $search_term) === 0 || strpos($name, $search_term) === 0)) {
                    $found_orders[] = $order;
                    break;
                }
            }
        }

        if (!empty($found_orders)) {
            echo '<table>';
            echo '<tr><th>Order</th><th>Status</th><th>SKU</th><th>Name</th><th>Quantity</th><th>Date</th></tr>';
            foreach ($found_orders as $order) {
                $order_data = $order->get_data();
                $order_date = $order->get_date_created();
                $formatted_date = $order_date->format('d/m/Y H:i');
                $order_status = wc_get_order_status_name($order_data['status']);

                echo '<tr>';
                echo '<td>#' . $order_data['id'] . '</td>';
                echo '<td>' . $order_status . '</td>';
                echo '<td>' . $sku . '</td>';
                echo '<td>' . $name . '</td>';
                echo '<td>' . $item->get_quantity() . '</td>';
                echo '<td>' . $formatted_date . '&nbsp;Hs.</td>';
                echo '</tr>';
            }
            echo '</table>';
        } else {
            echo 'Sorry no results.';
        }
    }
}

add_shortcode('order_search_result', 'search_orders_by_sku_or_product_name_result');
```

Any hint on how to make it work?

Comment: I  can't see anything wrong with it. Is it possible that all the SKUs you've searched for were purchased in the same order?

Comment: Hi Andrew, not at all.

Answer (score 0):

Try to use this code and check:

```
function search_orders_by_sku_or_product_name_form() {
    ob_start();
    ?>
    <form method="post" action="">
        <input type="text" name="order_search" placeholder="enter SKU o name">
        <input type="submit" value="Search">
    </form>
    <?php
    return ob_get_clean();
}
add_shortcode('order_search_form', 'search_orders_by_sku_or_product_name_form');

function search_orders_by_sku_or_product_name_result() {
    if (isset($_POST['order_search']) && !empty($_POST['order_search'])) {
        $search_term = sanitize_text_field($_POST['order_search']);
        $user_id = get_current_user_id();

        $orders = wc_get_orders(array(
            'customer' => $user_id,
            'limit' => -1,
        ));

        $found_orders = array();

        foreach ($orders as $order) {
            $order_items = $order->get_items();

            foreach ($order_items as $item) {
                $product = $item->get_product();
                if (!$product) {
                    continue;
                }

                $sku = $product->get_sku();
                $name = $product->get_name();
                if ( $sku && $name && (strpos($sku, $search_term) === 0 || strpos($name, $search_term) === 0) ) {
                    $found_orders[] = $order;
                    break;
                }
            }
        }

        if (!empty($found_orders)) {
            echo '<table>';
            echo '<tr><th>Order</th><th>Status</th><th>SKU</th><th>Name</th><th>Quantity</th><th>Date</th></tr>';
            foreach ($found_orders as $order) {
                $order_data = $order->get_data();
                $order_items = $order->get_items();
                $order_date = $order->get_date_created();
                $formatted_date = $order_date->format('d/m/Y H:i');
                $order_status = wc_get_order_status_name($order_data['status']);
                foreach ($order_items as $item) {
                    $product = $item->get_product();
                    echo '<tr>';
                    echo '<td>#' . $order_data['id'] . '</td>';
                    echo '<td>' . $order_status . '</td>';
                    echo '<td>' . $product->get_sku() . '</td>';
                    echo '<td>' . $product->get_name() . '</td>';
                    echo '<td>' . $item->get_quantity() . '</td>';
                    echo '<td>' . $formatted_date . '&nbsp;Hs.</td>';
                    echo '</tr>';
                }
            }
            echo '</table>';
        } else {
            echo 'Sorry no results.';
        }
    }
}

add_shortcode('order_search_result', 'search_orders_by_sku_or_product_name_result');
```

Comment: Hi SeoSiteSift, thanks for that! but it partially worked since keeps displaying results not for the exact SKU. ex: look for 123456789 and displays of course 123456789 plus other SKU with same contained characters. Can´t look for product name either. On the other side quantity is fixed.

Comment: @Hype orders only need to display logged in  user?

Comment: Hi SeoSiteSift, that´s right!

Answer (score 0):

Try to replace your 2nd function with the following, that will allow you to get customer orders with correct quantity, product name and SKU *(your first function stays unchanged)*:

```php
function search_orders_by_sku_or_product_name_result() {
    if (isset($_POST['order_search']) && !empty($_POST['order_search'])) {
        $search_term = sanitize_text_field($_POST['order_search']);

        $orders = wc_get_orders( array(
            'limit'    => -1,
            'customer' => get_current_user_id(),
        ) );

        $found_orders = array();

        if( $orders ) {
            foreach ( $orders as $order) {
                foreach ( $order->get_items() as $item ) {
                    $product = $item->get_product();
                    $sku     = $product->get_sku();
                    $name    = $product->get_name();
                    if ( $sku && $name && ( strpos($sku, $search_term) !== false || strpos($name, $search_term) !== false ) ) {
                        $found_orders[] = (object) array(
                            'number' => $order->get_order_number(),
                            'status' => wc_get_order_status_name($order->get_status()),
                            'sku'    => $sku,
                            'name'   => $name,
                            'qty'    => $item->get_quantity(),
                            'date'   => $order->get_date_created()->format('d/m/Y H:i'),
                        );
                        break;
                    }
                }
            }
        }

        if ( ! empty($found_orders) ) {
            echo '<table><tr><th>Order</th><th>Status</th><th>SKU</th><th>Name</th><th>Quantity</th><th>Date</th></tr>';

            foreach ( $found_orders as $order_data ) {
                echo '<tr>
                <td>#' . $order_data->number . '</td>
                <td>'  . $order_data->status . '</td>
                <td>'  . $order_data->sku . '</td>
                <td>'  . $order_data->name . '</td>
                <td>'  . $order_data->qty . '</td>
                <td>'  . $order_data->date . '&nbsp;Hs.</td>
                </tr>';
            }
            echo '</table>';
        } else {
            echo 'Sorry no results.';
        }
    }
}

add_shortcode('order_search_result', 'search_orders_by_sku_or_product_name_result');
```

Code goes in functions.php file of your child theme (or in a plugin). tested and works.

Comment: Hi LoicTheAztec, thanks for that!
Finally thorugh your coding I could find the solution; I´ve tried to paste it here but "StackOverflow" didn´t allow me.
I quote "Sorry, we are no longer accepting answers from your account because most of your answers need improvement or do not sufficiently answer the question. See the Help Center to learn more."

Comment: ok LoicTheAztec, thanks a lot, I´ll give it a try.
Best regards!